# Receive Azure topic messages into Web Job?

Tags: azure-webjobs, azureservicebus

How do we pump out messages from service bus topic's subscription.
I have been able to receive from service bus queue successfully.

```
 public class Functions
    {
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("mseoikeyword")] BrokeredMessage message, TextWriter log)
        {
            string strMsg;
            strMsg = message.GetBody<string>();
            log.WriteLine(strMsg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same trigger with topic path and subscription name as per [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Service-Bus#how-to-work-with-service-bus-topics).

Ensure topic and subscription exist as they will not be created by the trigger.